# Ingress redirect is failing with 404 not found

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have an application stack running on k8s.
To elaborate, My application stack consists of 5 micro services which includes one nginx front-end container.

we have the application stack running on 4 different namespace dev, uat1, uat2 and prod.

We would like leverage the use of ingress. we tried nginx ingress and the simple poc worked fine.
Now, with regards to our application: On a each namespace, a ingress is configured to access the frontend pod of that namespace.

to exemplify:
here is description of the ingress in namespace dev, uat and prod

dev

```
kubectl describe ing
Name:             ingress-dev
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        dev
Address:          x.x.x.x
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /frontend-dev  nginx-npm:8080 (x.x.x.x:8080)
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
```

uat

```
kubectl describe ing -n uat1
Name:             ingress-uat1
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        uat
Address:          x.x.x.x
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /frontend-uat  nginx-npm:8080 (x.x.x.x:8080)
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
```

prod

```
kubectl describe ing -n prod
Name:             ingress-prod
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        prod
Address:          x.x.x.x
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /frontend-prod  nginx-npm:8080 (x.x.x.x:8080)
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
```

However, I think the ingress is able to route the request to the backend pod but the application is hitting on 404 error.

It's not able to properly rewrite the target. Im getting lot of 404 errors like below

```
http://x.x.x.x/js/chunk-22d14dcf.6d9e354d.js   ---->404 Not Found

http://x.x.x.x/js/chunk-185d84c4.784aded4.js   ---->404 Not Found

http://x.x.x.x/js/chunk-e9a88af6.de1eafd9.js   ---->404 Not Found
```

what I tried and noticed differently is,
I changed the url, and added the ingress path next to the request URL ip. i hit HTTP 200 status code.

```
http://x.x.x.x/dev/js/chunk-22d14dcf.6d9e354d.js   ---->200 

http://x.x.x.x/dev/js/chunk-185d84c4.784aded4.js   ---->200

http://x.x.x.x/dev/js/chunk-e9a88af6.de1eafd9.js   ---->200
```

I noticed that the request is redirecting to http://x.x.x.x/js/chunk-22d14dcf.6d9e354d.js
Question i have is how to redirect the request to http://x.x.x.x/dev/js/chunk-22d14dcf.6d9e354d.js  or  http://x.x.x.x/uat/js/chunk-22d14dcf.6d9e354d.js  or  http://x.x.x.x/prod/js/chunk-22d14dcf.6d9e354d.js

Answer (score 0):

You can create the ingress someting like

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rewite-example
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /auth/api
        backend:
          serviceName: svc
          servicePort: 80
```

any request on **/auth/api** with get rewrite to **/api** and hit the service. Further you can create the something like `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /uat/$2`

So it will redirect all those requests to **/uat/$2**

**Update**

As suggested above here tested the local scenrio, check 404 throwing **Nginx** or **your application**. Above shared config working fine.

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-myservicea-two
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /uat/$2
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /auth/api(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: http-echo-server
            port:
              number: 8080
  ingressClassName: nginx
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: i already tried that but did not work as expected. @harsh manvar

Comment: updated the answer will example, check once working for me. Nginx ingress version : v1.0.0

Comment: sadly this did not work for me.