# How to use nginx ingress in kubernetes of gke?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I want to create an nginx load balancer in kubernetes.

```
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: ecom-ingress
    spec:
      defaultBackend:
        service:
          name: ecom-ui-service
          port:
            number: 80
      rules:
      - http:
          paths:
          - path: /identity
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: ecom-identity-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /catalog
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: ecom-catalog-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

So I have created services and pods on cluster. And now I want to create an ingress to access my servies using rewrite.

- http://ip-of-cubernetes    (main mape)
- http://ip-of-cubernetes/catalog    (list prodcts)
- http://ip-of-cubernetes/catalog/112    (single prodcut)

When I send this nginx yml file using kubectl command "kubectl apply -f ingress.yml" it creates a gce load balancer in ingress tab of google page like following. And I can not access the catalog endpoint. It returns nginx 404 page.
[image]

if I use following helm command in google management page console, it creates a loadbalancer in services tab.

```
 helm install nginx-ingress nginx-stable/nginx-ingress --set rbac.create=true
```

[image]

So I want to create an nginx loadbalancer in services tab or I want to use rewrite rules in gce loadbalancers.

How can I specify my ingress yml file for this purpose? And I want to use the rewrite for use my services to use query strings etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-networking-recipes/tree/main/ingress/single-cluster/ingress-nginx) one of the use case is rewrite request URI before sending it to application.

There is also information about yaml deployment in ingress and in service that you can use as a guidance in your deployment.

Comment: This example includes a domain (host: foo.example.com) in igress, but ingress creates a random public ip. So how can I access it?

Comment: By configuring your DNS A record and pointing your domain to the IP address of your ingress. For example, you use Cloud DNS as your DNS server. You can use this [link](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/set-up-dns-records-domain-name) as a guidance on how you can configure your A record.

From the example, under “Create A record to point the domain to an external IP address” you will see that the configuration is A record and there is an option you will put the IP address. That is how you can point your domain to the IP address of your ingress.

Comment: I used the solution in the link. and seperated the ui and backend ingresses. So I added  ip that generated by google to windows host file for a specific custom url.

Answer (score 1):

So you have installed the ingress controller which will manage the ingress objects.

Here is official link you can refer for more details : https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke

Make sure your ingress pointing to proper **ingress class** if you are using the **Nginx** or GCE any other controller :

**Example** :

```
apiVersion:  networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo-external
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
```

You can create the **ingress** **object** file

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: service-1
            port:
              number: 8080
```

So if you have a **single service** you can use the above ingress. So any request at **example.com** will get redirected to **service-1**

```
http://ip-of-cubernetes (main page)
http://ip-of-cubernetes/catalog (list prodcts)
http://ip-of-cubernetes/catalog/112 (single product)


    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: ingress-resource
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    spec:
      rules:
      - host: example.com
        http:
          paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: service-1
                port:
                  number: 8080
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /catalog
            backend:
              service:
                name: service-2
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Sharing here my other routing example which you can refer for rewriting the path if you required it.

Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75433607/5525824

Comment: this is good solution, but my service-1 is frontend like javascript single page app and service2- is web rest api. So frontend works, but example.com/catalog does not work

Comment: you might need to do some minor changes accordingly in above shared yaml maybe adding path like /catalog/ and test around.